# Differences using 'and' operator and '&' operator in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

Recently, I'm working with my course assignment about image processing with OpenCV. I just want to ask, why the 'and' operator differs in result with '&' operator because it gives significant differences on the picture? Just see the pictures on the link below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you just add an `!` before image links they will be displayed inline.

Comment: how are the images related to the question?

Comment: The `and` operates on boolean values, `&` operates on bits of integers.

Comment: @wookiekim He didn't post the code, but presumably he's using the operators in some kind of masking loop on the pixel values.